# Хочу проверить свои знания пайтона

Tags: python

Изучаю python уже 3 месяца, хотелось бы как-то проверить свои знания, может есть какие-то тесты или бесплатные курсы с рядом заданий? Был бы благодарен, если бы таковой скинули.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот неплохие проверки для Python - делайте только задачи, если хотите (там и комментарии, есть, если "застрянете"):

курс с самого нуля: https://stepik.org/course/58852/promo,

начальный курс: https://stepik.org/course/67/syllabus,

курс для продвинутых: https://stepik.org/course/512/syllabus

курс с задачами: https://pythontutor.ru/